# Increase performance of Hive query with join

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
hive -e "select e.school_id, e.school_name, e.school_location  from
(select  r.college_id, r.college_name
from
    College r
where
    college_id = '6789') tab1
full outer join
(select e.school_id, e.school_name, e.school_location 
 from  university
 lateral view explode(school) encTable as e
 where
     school_id = '12345') tab2
   on tab1.school_id=tab2.college_id
   limit 4 " > result456.csv
```

I am currently running a hive query where I am joining 2 tables university and college where collecge_id matches with school_id 
of University, This taking more time to execute since I have more data in both University and College
Is there any update needed to increase performance of this query

Here it is collecting all data from College and then School, then it is comparing **tab1.school_id=tab2.college_id** 
which I feel poor in performance

Is there any other way we can fetch same data with increasing performance

Comment: (1) When you are asking for performance improvement, the minimum is to mention what are the current and desired execution times. (2) The query makes no sense. Give a data sample including required results.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for slow response from your cluster processing for hive query. 
Some of the optimization factors, you may need to consider are mentioned below –

1. You may need to consider the use of ‘Bucketing’ for your data in both tables to which may be helpful to do the join operation while using map joins.  In case,  school_id and college_id are unique values than partitioning the data (partitioned table feature) will not appropriate to use. 
   Please refer the link to get more information on join optimisation - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+JoinOptimization
2. You may also need to think about parallel processing optimization for your query. Please refere the below link for more details on syntax - https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/48919/how-can-i-set-hive-to-run-in-parallel-execution-to.html
3. I could see in your hive query that you are using ‘full outer join’ which is quite expensive. As you have not mentioned the requirement and sample data so it is not possible to comment if we can avoid full outer join to get the desired result.
4. Depending on the data size you may also need to adjust the appropriate block size of the cluster.
5. Could you please also try to look into the reducer numbers, it is recommended that one should have between 0.95 to 1.75 times of your maps. In addition, reducer should have enough data to process around block size and at least 5 to 15 minutes.
6. The best way is use ‘EXPLAIN’, or ‘Illustrate’ commands (depending on your hive version )to see the how the plan being used for processing your query. It will give your more insight for optimization.

There is no hard and fast rule to get the optimized configuration for all clusters.  You may need to try and test different options to reach at optimized level.